# how to get typechecking on dynamic methods?

Tags: typescript, dynamic, runtime, typechecking

I have a TS object that delegates some actions to another class instance. But since this instance is created at runtime, I'm having trouble getting typechecking on the method calls.
Something like:

```js
    // main bot class
    class TixBot extends BaseBot implements IBot  {

      public actions: BotActions

      constructor(room: IRoom) {
        super()
        // based on situation we may delegate to a different actions bot
        this.actions = new TixyActions(this)
      }

    }

    // class to handle actions varies by bot
    class TixyActions implements BotActions {

      public helpText(lang: ILang): string {
        return "something"
      }
    }
```

so in other code I have an instance of the TixBot 
and try to call the `actions.helpText()` of its internal reference:

```js
    tixbotInstance.actions.helpText('en')
```

But I can't get any typechecking on this method.
The typedefs so far look a bit like this:

```js
    //types/index.d.ts

    export interface BotActions {
      helpText(lang: ILang): string
    }

    export interface IBot {
      actions: IBotActions
```

So is there a way to use casting or type guards or something to allow me to see inside VScode all of the actions?

There is no actual error thrown but just no typechecking or VSCode intellisense on the method.

eg I can type this with no compile time issues, a method that doesn't exist on the dynamic instance.

```js
    const introText:string = tixy.actions.foo() // no error!!
```

So `tixy.actions` even though it's created at runtime, does have a declared type/interface so I would have thought TS would be able to peek in and stop me from typing stupid stuff.

Comment: *I'm having trouble getting typechecking on the method calls*: what does that mean, precisely? Post the exact and complete error you get. Note that: 1. your class use a string as argument to helpText(), but your interface uses an ILang; 2. you're calling helpText() without passing any argument.

Comment: means there is no typechecking available at compile time. i can type anything and it compiles, added an example to clarify (and cleaned up demo code above to match codebase, good catch)

Comment: Your `tixy`variable is probably declared as `any` instead of `IBot` or `TixBot`. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: no the instance is declared: `public actions: BotActions`. The code is part of a large codebase so a little hard to isolate. the above is accurate though.

Comment: If you can't produce a [mcve] it's hard for anyone who isn't at your computer to figure it out.  Try reproducing your issue in a standalone/web IDE. If you can do that, post your code here.  If not, then your environment differs in some way you should be able to debug.  Good luck!